# Regex: replace anything and inside quotes

Tags: regex

I'm trying to do a find/replace with my code editor for the font icons' PUA generated codes. The reason why I ask is because the string contains backspace escape and have no idea how to write it.

Example: `content: "\e034"` to be `content:`.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Just use `content:\s"[^"]*"` and replace with `content:`.

Comment: Thanks so much, but why didn't you score?

Comment: If it works, I can post as an answer. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match something between delimiters you do not need to know what is inside. Just leave the job to the *negated character class*:

```
content:\s"[^"]*"
```

The `[^"]` is a negated character class matching any character other than a double quote.

Replace with `content:`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pQ7vB0/1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation again. According to my calculation I was ready to "escape the escape" :)